# Wordpress x owl-carousel mobile bug

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have some problem with my wordpress template. On screenshot(1), you may see how site views on PC. If we resize site on PC - all good.

[image: pc]

And if we go to site with mobile device, we see overlay divs. Div news on div owl-carousel with slides.

[image: resize]

I think its for long loading script owl-carousel. I rearranged script src on header from footer - not working. Help me pls.

Comment: Try remove height:100% in  .posstatic {} in style.css line 6914

Comment: add `.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { display: table; content: " ";}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }`

Comment: sorry, but this dont work too =(

Comment: did you try to inspect ipad in safari

Comment: ofc, and in chrome

Comment: I don't have ipad, on tommorow in office i will check it.